How to dynamically apply array column typing in Spark
I have a PySpark DataFrame with a string column that contains JSON data structured as arrays of objects. However, the schema of these JSON objects can vary from row to row.
Here’s an example of two rows in the DataFrame:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| column                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"_t":"TypeA","id":"123","value":"100","details":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}}]                 |
| [{"_t":"TypeB","id":"456","extra_field":"info","other_details":{"key3":"val3","key4":"val4"}}]    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


First row: Contains JSON objects with fields _t, id, value, and a
nested details object.
Second row: Contains JSON objects with fields
_t, id, extra_field, and a nested other_details object.

I need to convert the column from a string type to an array type, with the schema dynamically inferred to accommodate all variations in the JSON structure. Currently, my approach only works for the first row and doesn't account for schema variations.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
from pyspark.sql.functions import schema_of_json, from_json, col

json_sample = df.select("column").head()[0]  # Sample JSON from the first row
inferred_schema = schema_of_json(json_sample)    # Infer schema from the sample

# Convert the column to array type using the inferred schema
df = df.withColumn("column", from_json(col("column"), inferred_schema))

Issue:
The inferred schema only matches the first row's JSON structure. As a result, rows with different schemas (e.g., the second row) fail to parse correctly.
I’m looking for a way to:
Dynamically infer the schema for the column to handle all variations in the JSON objects across rows.
Apply the inferred schema to convert the column into an array type without losing any data.
Real data example, one row:
[{'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': '29b2c17e-e980-4e3f-bd6a-a311f414bd25', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': 'f794288a-6c38-4dd5-bc3a-f3d81e2e824a', 'Value': '0.00', 'Percent': '0'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.000232200', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '150000.00', 'PricingLmi': '150000.00', 'PureRate': '0.000232200', 'PurePremium': '34.83'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '85.64', 'DaFix': '7.99', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '125.94117647058823529411764706', 'DiscountValue': '50.38', 'CommercialPremium': '75.56', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '40.301176470588235294117647059', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '75.564705882352941176470588236', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.000503733'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '5.58', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '81.14', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '40.301176470588235294117647059', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '24.180705882352941176470588236', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-3.43', 'NetPremium': '51.38', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '19.98'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': 'a564e803-3ea5-4336-9ae7-5bb70d62916b', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '150000.00'}]}, {'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': 'ca1cc323-0f42-4661-951e-dfad7027d9b6', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': 'ad9c664c-06b4-408a-8e2f-2c664c45a137', 'Value': '0.00', 'Percent': '0'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.000494500', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '15000.00', 'PricingLmi': '15000.00', 'PureRate': '0.000494500', 'PurePremium': '7.42'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '30.8', 'DaFix': '7.98', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '45.294117647058823529411764706', 'DiscountValue': '18.12', 'CommercialPremium': '27.18', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '14.494117647058823529411764706', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '27.176470588235294117647058824', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.001812'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '2.01', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '29.19', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '14.494117647058823529411764706', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '8.696470588235294117647058824', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-1.23', 'NetPremium': '18.48', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '12.29'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': '5f809eaf-6a80-4eb3-a36a-e71014d7e888', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '15000.00'}]}, {'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': '00e41c0f-eb68-4e24-8898-66fd54e560dd', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': 'b4e2babc-7ea4-49e5-9c73-5b3265b07ccb', 'Value': '0.00', 'Percent': '0'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.010913400', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '3000.00', 'PricingLmi': '3000.00', 'PureRate': '0.010913400', 'PurePremium': '32.74'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '81.44', 'DaFix': '7.98', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '119.76470588235294117647058824', 'DiscountValue': '47.91', 'CommercialPremium': '71.86', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '38.324705882352941176470588237', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '71.858823529411764705882352944', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.023953333'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '5.30', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '77.16', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '38.324705882352941176470588237', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '22.994823529411764705882352942', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-3.26', 'NetPremium': '48.86', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '19.38'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': 'a564e803-3ea5-4336-9ae7-5bb70d62916b', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '3000.00'}]}, {'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': 'd044866e-f5f5-4a42-b68f-23aa2c55b498', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': '0f9b9edb-2a35-4300-b1e5-d61e90636c66', 'Value': '1000', 'Percent': '0.15'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.001363100', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '30000.00', 'PricingLmi': '30000.00', 'PureRate': '0.001363100', 'PurePremium': '40.89'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '97.74', 'DaFix': '7.98', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '143.73529411764705882352941176', 'DiscountValue': '57.49', 'CommercialPremium': '86.24', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '45.995294117647058823529411763', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '86.24117647058823529411764706', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.002874667'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '6.35', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '92.59', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '45.995294117647058823529411763', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '27.597176470588235294117647059', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-3.91', 'NetPremium': '58.64', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '21.66'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': 'a564e803-3ea5-4336-9ae7-5bb70d62916b', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '30000.00'}]}, {'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': 'b2df01da-0b28-4425-8e68-1728395804f8', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': '23e3f5e1-1a25-4920-a8f9-2a68bb7505d3', 'Value': '150.00', 'Percent': '0.1'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.005820050', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '2000.00', 'PricingLmi': '2000.00', 'PureRate': '0.005820050', 'PurePremium': '11.64'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '39.24', 'DaFix': '7.98', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '57.705882352941176470588235294', 'DiscountValue': '23.08', 'CommercialPremium': '34.62', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '18.465882352941176470588235294', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '34.623529411764705882352941176', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.01731'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '2.56', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '37.18', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '18.465882352941176470588235294', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '11.079529411764705882352941176', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-1.57', 'NetPremium': '23.54', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '13.47'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': 'a564e803-3ea5-4336-9ae7-5bb70d62916b', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '2000.00'}]}, {'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': '7fa48879-43e5-493b-bb90-ff7998232847', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': '6c8d2e6f-5390-4a3b-b14e-79a44d5bec64', 'Value': '500.00', 'Percent': '0.1'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.006439250', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '3000.00', 'PricingLmi': '3000.00', 'PureRate': '0.006439250', 'PurePremium': '19.32'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '54.6', 'DaFix': '7.98', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '80.29411764705882352941176471', 'DiscountValue': '32.12', 'CommercialPremium': '48.18', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '25.694117647058823529411764707', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '48.176470588235294117647058826', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.01606'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '3.56', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '51.74', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '25.694117647058823529411764707', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '15.416470588235294117647058824', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-2.18', 'NetPremium': '32.76', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '15.62'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': 'a564e803-3ea5-4336-9ae7-5bb70d62916b', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '3000.00'}]}, {'_t': 'UniqueLmiCoverageCalculation', 'CoverageId': '795c1e26-2eb7-4b55-b23a-765850699aeb', 'Operation': 'Add', 'Deductible': {'_id': 'e8996734-39d5-4983-8b41-8d7c23c73a12', 'Value': '0.00', 'Percent': '0'}, 'Subscription': {'RiskRate': '0.000273050', 'LoadingFee': '0', 'DerivedLmi': '3000.00', 'PricingLmi': '3000.00', 'PureRate': '0.000273050', 'PurePremium': '0.82'}, 'Product': {'NetPremiumWithoutDiscount': '17.6', 'DaFix': '7.98', 'DaPercentage': '0.14', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36'}, 'Commercial': {'CommercialPremiumWithoutDiscount': '25.882352941176470588235294118', 'DiscountValue': '10.35', 'CommercialPremium': '15.53', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'CommissionValue': '8.282352941176470588235294118', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'ProLaboreValue': '0', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'CommercialPremiumWithDiscountAndFee': '15.529411764705882352941176471', 'MinimumPremiumLoadingFee': '0', 'CommercialFee': '0.005176667'}, 'Financial': {'Iof': '1.15', 'IofPercentage': '0.0738', 'GrossPremium': '16.68', 'FinancialCharge': '0.00', 'InstallmentCost': '0.00', 'InstallmentCostPercentage': '0.0', 'FinancialRefundAmount': '0'}, 'Audit': {'CommissionWithoutDiscount': '8.282352941176470588235294118', 'ProLaboreWithoutDiscount': '0', 'Commission': '4.9694117647058823529411764707', 'ProLabore': '0', 'Profit': '-0.70', 'NetPremium': '10.56', 'ProfitPercentage': '0.36', 'CommercialLoadingFee': '0.000000000', 'Discount': '0.400000000', 'ProLaborePercentage': '0', 'CommissionPercentage': '0.320000000', 'MinimumPremiumDA': '0', 'TotalDA': '10.44'}, 'IndemnityPeriod': None, 'InsuredObjects': [{'RiskId': 'a564e803-3ea5-4336-9ae7-5bb70d62916b', 'RiskVersion': '2.1', 'Operation': 'Add', 'InsuredAmount': '3000.00'}]}]


It's not quite clear to me what you expect as the output in the end. Can you take a much simpler json example (because the json you've shown is quite long and complicated) and show what you expect as the final dataframe output from it in the form a table?

@SachinHosmani, I revised my question, see if it's clearer now.

Why is your column a list of json objects? Can you have multiple objects in the same row?

Added an answer assuming it's a list of json objects in the input string

@SachinHosmani that worked well for the example, but for some reason it's not working for my real data, I'm facing the error "Some of types cannot be determined after inferring". I added one row of example data in the topic. .

That is huge and I can't debug it manually. Try one field at a time and tell which field it fails at. Also please reply on the answer's comments below.

@SachinHosmani I found the problem.. It was the value None in the data. Thank you for the help.

You can create an RDD with the column you concern and then load this RDD into dataframe using spark.read.json(), Spark will infer and merge the schema automatically for you, see below:
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col

rdd = df.select('column').rdd.map(lambda x: x['column'])

inferred_schema = ArrayType(spark.read.json(rdd).schema)

df = df.withColumn("column", from_json(col("column"), inferred_schema))

You can set samplingRatio (default=1.0) when creating dataframe with spark.read.json() to use a fraction of rows for schema inferring.

I think the only approach would be to just merge the schemas from all the rows in the dataframe and use that as the inferred schema while creating the new column. It's not efficient, but if you just such heterogenous data in your dataframe, I don't see any other option. So this is not an ideal situation, but you can make it work. Here is a solution
Sample data
data = [
    ('[{"_t":"TypeA","id":"123","value":"100","details":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}}]',),
    ('[{"_t":"TypeB","id":"456","extra_field":"info","other_details":{"key3":"val3","key4":"val4"}}]',)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["column"])


Collect all the schema rows from your data frame
json_rows = df.select("column").rdd.flatMap(lambda row: row).collect()

Utility functions to infer the schema from a row and merge schemas from all rows
def infer_schema(json_strings):
    schemas = []
    for json_string in json_strings:
        parsed = json.loads(json_string)
        df = spark.createDataFrame(parsed)
        schemas.append(df.schema)
    return schemas

def merge_schemas(schemas):
    base_schema = StructType()
    for schema in schemas:
        for field in schema:
            if field.name not in [f.name for f in base_schema.fields]:
                base_schema.add(field)
    return ArrayType(base_schema)


Get a single merged schema
merged_schema = merge_schemas(infer_schema(json_rows))

Use the merged schema while creating the new column
df_parsed = df.withColumn("column", from_json(col("column"), merged_schema))

df_parsed.show(truncate=False)

df_parsed.printSchema()

Produces
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|column                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{TypeA, {key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2}, 123, 100, NULL, NULL}] |
|[{TypeB, NULL, 456, NULL, info, {key3 -> val3, key4 -> val4}}]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _t: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- extra_field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- other_details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)


How is this any more efficient than just allowing spark to infer the schema from the entire file?

How do you make Spark infer the schema from an entire dataframe where the schema is contained in a string column and the schema varies from row to row?

Sorry, didn't read the original post closely enough...
